# Allow an external user to use Google Cloud Plataform account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created an account on Google Cloud Platform, but another user will need access to this account to work with me on managing the virtual machines.

How can I grant this access for this user to have access to a specific project?

I know that Google Ads and Google Analytics have options for this type of operation, but I haven't found anything similar on Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone accessing a GCP project will require a [google account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?hl=en), but it need not be associated to your organization.

You can then add the user in the GCP IAM screen simply using their email address.

[image: locator to IAM control]

Then, add the user's email with appropriate roles.  To work on the VMs, they will need Compute Admin role.

[image]

Once granted access, they will be able to use the `gcloud` commands or pantheon UI to administer the instances and gain access to the consoles.

Comment: With IAM, can I force the user to log in only if he has 2FA enabled?

Comment: No.  Only their org admin can force that.  If you have a workspace org, you can create an account in your org and enforce MFA.